# How to get Smtp server name from mail

Tags: asp.net, email, server, smtp

Scenario:

In my web application (ASP.NET MVC + C# + JS...), I have input with email address. Is there any possible way to get its SMTP server name for most common cases?

e.g. smtp.gmail.com for foo@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are talking about the MX record.  When you want to send email to a gmail.com email address, you look up the Mail Exchange (MX) record:

```
$ host -t mx gmail.com
gmail.com mail is handled by 20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com mail is handled by 10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

Typically, the first host to try is the one with the shortest distance.  In this case that is gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com with a distance of 5.

```
$ telnet gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com 25
Trying 74.125.197.109...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP w63-v6sm8014513pfa.135 - gsmtp
ehlo there
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [4.78.245.197]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
quit
221 2.0.0 closing connection w63-v6sm8014513pfa.135 - gsmtp
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: @zolty13 Yes, C# has networking libraries that you can use to write code that looks up MX records.  I did a quick google search for "c# dns mx lookup" and got close to 90,000 hits.  Some of them were here on stackoverflow.

Comment: @zolty13 It sounds like you are planning to write your own networking code for some reason.  It would probably make more sense for you to use an MTA like [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/).  Your web application could just use a C# SMTP client library to send email directly to your own MTA.  The MTA would do the DNS lookups and deliver the email to the correct SMTP server.

Comment: So i do not neet to have smtp port and server name?

Comment: @zolty13 If you use your own MTA, it would figure out the server name for you.  The smtp port is pretty much always port 25, and the MTA knows that.

Comment: it is pretty always 465.
Please, edit your answet, then i accept and we delete comments.

Comment: @zolty13 MTAs listen on port 25 for inbound mail.  Port 465 is sometimes used for mail submission, but its use is deprecated: port 587 is the current standard. Some ISPs, including GMail, configure their MSAs to listen on both 465 and 587 for compatibility with mail clients that follow the old standard. 

Bottom line: if your MTA is sending email **to** a GMail address, it will connect to GMail's MTA on port 25.  If you are trying to connect to GMail to send outbound email that appears to be **from** your Gmail account, you will send through GMail's MSA (using either port 465 or 587).

Comment: Unfortunately not. If i want to send mail in my web app (C#) i have to use 465 port

Comment: Gmail supports connections on both port 465 and 587.  (See https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600)  If you can connect on port  465 but not 587, your firewall might be the cause.  Note that you will have to negotiate STARTTLS to send mail using port 587.

Comment: Why is it that you got "gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com" back but you connected to "gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com"? That doesn't make any sense